# Как удалить репозиторий из списка слева на главной Гитхаба?

Tags: github

Репозиторий не мой, я его не форкал, просто создал issue, но сейчас закрыл. От уведомлений отписался. Я им даже не пользуюсь, просто глаза мозолит. Как решить вопрос?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: удалить попробуйте: Settings - Danger Zone - Delete this repository

Comment: @trollingchar Репозиторий не мой. Это просто ссылка  на чужой реп, там нет вкладки settings, давно бы уже удалил)

Comment: воспроизвел проблему для теста, теперь я тоже не могу его удалить

Comment: @trollingchar Ща написал в саппорт, посмотрим, шо скажут

Comment: @trollingchar есть ответ. Пообщавшись с мужиком из саппорта, узнал от него, что в этом списке висят репозитории, с которыми мы как-либо взаимодействовали. И, внимание, удаляются они из этого списка автоматически спустя 4 месяца после взаимодействия.

Comment: Интересно. Если вы оформите это ответом, я плюс поставлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пообщавшись с мужиком из саппорта, узнал от него, что в этом списке висят репозитории, с которыми мы как-либо взаимодействовали. **И, внимание, удаляются они из этого списка автоматически спустя 4 месяца после взаимодействия.**

Answer (score 0):

Покинуть репозиторий к которому вам дали доступ

https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/removing-yourself-from-a-collaborators-repository

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, 
сказано:  _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.
Это сообщение, пожалуйста, или поправте, или удалите.